# SQL Injection on JDBC Driver - MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, coldfusion, sql-injection

Okay so basically I'm a little bit stumped. This question is regarding the JDBC driver. Basically we own a server that is hosted on this driver, and it's running MYSQL. We are using coldfusion as our language of choice. We have a GET parameter `?lang=` and injecting the character '\' into it prompts the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near` and no other character causes this error. I am sort of worried here. Can anyone tell me how an attacker would approach an sql injection attack into this parameter? So I can understand how I can filter it because in my code I am properly filtering preg_match on `\` character and yet I still get this error. How would I be able to inject this parameter? Can someone point me to a guide or something, or if it's even possible. Just so I can rest in piece assuming it's not. But anyhow if this information is necessary the mysql version is `5.1.30` and the exact driver name is `MySQL-AB JDBC Driver`. Thanks for taking your time to help me out!

Comment: _"I am properly filtering preg_match"_ - uh? CFML doesn't have preg_match; that's PHP. I don't really understand what you're saying, but the primary way to prevent SQL injection is to use parameterised queries, via [cfqueryparam](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam)

Comment: I am asking how would I protect my server from sql injection. Or if you can send me some kind of article, pdf, or tutorial of how to inject a JDBC driver running MYSQL

Comment: You protect your server by not allowing arbitrary SQL to run. For a webapp this means parameterised queries. I don't understand your focus on the JDBC driver itself. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\` can be an escape character in mysql.

For example, an attacker could use the `\b` sequence to delete portions of your query and rewrite with their own injected sql.

The most reliable way to prevent sql injection attacks is to use parametrized queries.

See also:

- [Mysql character escape sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences)
- [Preventing Sql Injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)
- [Using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Also be aware that in many databases (not absolutely sure about the JDBC/Mysql combination) it is also possible to "inject" a wildcard character into a sql `LIKE` clause, even with a parametrized query.  "Injection" in this particular case is not always a problem - in fact, in many cases it may be exactly the desired behavior.  However, it can be a problem, if for example, you were doing something horrid like `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName LIKE @userInput AND Password LIKE @passwordInput` (which would allow anyone to log in simply by inputing the `%` wildcard character on  the screen for both fields).

Comment: I don't get what you mean with the `\b` - when I add that to the query my site will redirect me back to the home page. What I am asking formally is how to inject these type of cases. More directly. Can an attacker get my login credentials through this type of character injection?

Comment: `\b` is just one potential way of modifying the sql in ways that you don't intend - and may not be a successful attack in all cases.  You may also find https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection helpful for some more examples.